# How do I get the file upload URL from the JSON Webhook?

Tags: cognito-forms, zapier

I saw this question asked about a year and a half ago.  Is this close to being possible?

This is what happens when I try to use a webhook in Zapier or in Workato as a trigger:

[image: Zapier Upload]

I would use the Cognito form trigger with Zapier but it will never update from default data when setting up the zap.

[image: Cognito Trigger]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The uploaded file is sent over to Zapier, it shows up in the list of files as 'Entry_Document1' and 'Entry_Document2', each refers to a File Upload field on your Cognito Form. You can use these to pull the document out of Cognito Forms and into your own system.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  I agree if you use the zapier integration that works and it also come shows the file upload in one other place.

Comment: I was trying to use a webhook instead of the zapier - cognito integration.  

If you use requestbin to test the webhook it shows the file upload like this:"TestUpload": [
  {
   "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
   "Id": "F-NuMqmlbNxY439O$ouuxAtu",
   "IsEncrypted": false,
   "Name": "background.jpg",
   "Size": 649488,
   "File": "https://services.cognitoforms.com/fa/M5zqQi5BAEWXqD_Nc4aMuw?token=6fEFeT5NGCZ2LarTtzn0JbW-dtlFosY9c6IwFbwcdc_8TKecN_OCn2viLrIV7CJ2p8jcP1JIsRDwI77MQ8TSPg$$"
  }   How can I use the webhook to get the file?

Comment: I am trying to use a repeating section and zapier does not like arrays.  Workato however handles arrays from a webhook just fine.